# JDBC - Query returns no values

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to make a query that returns a simple series of results using JDBC on a java class. The Query only needs 1 join for it to work yet, for some reason, it does not return any values. However, when this query is ran on the Oracle SQL Developer, the correct results are shown. below is the code i am currently using.

### To Access Database

```
query = "select h.house_id, h.house_address, h.house_type, h.status, l.firstname, l.surname, h.price_per_month "
                  + "from houses_tbl h join landlord_tbl l on l.landlord_id = h.landlord_id";

conn = connectToDatabase();
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(query);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

### To Retrieve Data

```
response.setContentType("application/json");

fullJsonString = "{";
fullJsonString += "\"houses\":[";
ArrayList<HouseObj> allHouses = new ArrayList<HouseObj>();
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        int houseID = rs.getInt(1);
        Struct address = (Struct) rs.getObject(2);
        Object[] taskAddress = address.getAttributes();
        String houseAddressStreet = taskAddress[0].toString();
        String houseAddressTown = taskAddress[1].toString();
        String houseAddressCounty = taskAddress[2].toString();
        String houseAddressCountry = taskAddress[3].toString();
        String houseAddressPostcode = taskAddress[4].toString();
        String houseFullAddress = houseAddressStreet + ", "
                + houseAddressTown + ", " + houseAddressCounty
                + ", " + houseAddressCountry + ", "
                + houseAddressPostcode;
        String type = rs.getString(3);
        String status = rs.getString(4);
        String landlord = rs.getString(5)+" "+rs.getString(6);
        int price = rs.getInt(7);

        HouseObj newClient = new HouseObj(houseID,
        houseFullAddress, type, status, landlord, price);
        allHouses.add(newClient);
    }

    System.out.println("Number Of Houses : "+allHouses.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < allHouses.size(); i++) {
        if (i == allHouses.size() - 1) {
            fullJsonString += "{\"id\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getHouseId() + "\","
                    + "\"address\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getAddress() + "\","
                    + "\"type\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getType() + "\","
                    + "\"status\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getStatus() + "\","
                    + "\"landlord\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getLandlord() + "\","
                    + "\"price\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getPrice() + "\"}";
        } else {
            fullJsonString += "{\"id\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getHouseId() + "\","
                    + "\"address\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getAddress() + "\","
                    + "\"type\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getType() + "\","
                    + "\"status\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getStatus() + "\","
                    + "\"landlord\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getLandlord() + "\","
                    + "\"price\":\""
                    + allHouses.get(i).getPrice() + "\"},";
        }

    }
    fullJsonString += "]}";

} //Catch Exception Below
```

### Output

```
Number Of Houses : 0
{"houses":[]}
```

Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

From your posted code, I don't see any printing of the resultset.
How do you know it's not returning anything?
Can you put a print statement before/after the while (rs.next) cycle (an if, a counter) to see if it' s actually empty?
If it is empty, try removing table alias from your query

EDIT:
Modify the query in "select house_id from houses_tbl", execute the query and exactly after

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

put

```
if (rs.next()){ 
    System.out.println("Got house!"); 
}else{ 
    System.out.println("No houses here!"); 
}
```

and momentarily comment out/bypass the printing code. This is to check baseline operativity of you env in that context. If this doesn't work, must be a database/driver issue, to me

Comment: If you need to know more details about the OP's issue, please add your query as a comment not as an answer :)

Comment: I have edited the above code to show you how i am printing the string and what the result is.

Comment: @arkantos :thanks for your reminder, i thought about it.Unfortunately I'm not allowed to comment (reputation needed: 50). Can you tell me how can I do, in this case? I tried to help in this answer as per question's last sentence "Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated", which "vaguely" classifies my answer as an "answer". What dou you think?

Comment: @ChrisGraves if System.out.println(allHouses.size()) prints '0' (not shown) all I can say is: check that you are connecting to the same DB in Java as the one with SQL Developer (maybe different similar instances exists?) and check that the variable 'rs' (very common name) is not overwritten and is actually pointing to the right place

Comment: I have used the same connection for different query's, all of which work perfectly. This is the only one i have had trouble with.

Comment: @Diego1974.. Have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead#214174) to know more about the question you asked :)

Comment: @ChrisGraves If table aliases are supported in your environment, can you check the retrieve part with a little check after `rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`  maybe the correct resulset is not passed to the printing code... It's a strange case...

Comment: Just changed the name of the ResultSet to make sure it was the right ResultSet being called again and still no results.

Comment: @ChrisGraves Modify the query in "select house_id from houses_tbl", execute the query and exactly after
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

put
`if (rs.next()){
 System.out.println("Got house!");
}else{
 System.out.println("No houses here!");
}`

and momentarily comment out/bypass the printing code.
This is to check baseline operativity of you env in that context.
If this doesn't work, must be a database/driver issue, to me