# Database INSERT not adding data to table

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to run two queries, one to create a table and another to insert some value in it. Table is getting created but value is not getting added to the table.

```
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        //Creating the Database if not Already Present
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists senti "
                + "( latitude double NULL, "
                + "longitude double NULL, "
                +  "Sentiment varchar(30)  NULL) ";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();

        //System.out.println(count + "count");


        stmt1 = c.createStatement();
        String sql1 = "INSERT INTO senti     values(25.62010856,85.13277482,'neutral')";

        stmt1.executeUpdate(sql1)
```

Comment: What kind of database is this? Do you have autocommit set? (Have you tried using `c.commit()`?)

Comment: I am sorry to have missed that part. I am using MySql and using this code  c.setAutoCommit(false);

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746044/jdbc-query-returns-no-values

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you've called

```
c.setAutoCommit(false)
```

... but then you haven't committed the update. So no, that *won't* have updated the database. Just use

```
c.commit();
```

after the update - or turn auto-commit back on instead. If you were expecting the table not to be created until you called `commit()`, basically [DDL statements can't be rolled back](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html) so you shouldn't try to include those within a larger transaction.